# Создание экземпляров, реализующих единый интерфейс, имеющих различные конструкторы c#

Tags: c#, конструктор

Предположим, у нас есть следующие интерфейсы:

```
public interface IAddIn {
    string IAddInType();
}
public interface ISomeInterface { }
public interface ISomeInterface2 { }
```

Также существует несколько классов, реализующих интерфейс `IAddIn` (в различных вариациях)

```
public class A : IAddIn {
    public A () 
    {
        // Do some initialization
    }
}
public class B : IAddIn, ISomeInterface {
    public B(string param1, int param2)
    {
         // Do some initialization
    }
}
public class C : IAddIn {
    public C(ISomeInterface param1) 
    {
        // Do some initialization
    }
}
public class C : IAddIn {
    public C(ISomeInterface2 param1) 
    {
        // Do some initialization
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что классы не могут работать без инициализации, также возможно, что в будущем появятся другие реализации `IAddIn` с другими параметрами.

Класс-клиент динамически подгружая все реализации `IAddIn` в зависимости от его типа создает реализации `ISomeInterface` или `ISomeInterface2` (которым также нужны различные параметры) или передает эти параметры непосредственно в класс (например, как класс `B`, который самостоятельно реализует `ISomeInterface` на основе параметров).

Есть ли какой-либо механизм универсального создания экземпляров?

**Update**
Класс клиента создает несколько экземпляров каждого класса (5,30,50) с различными параметрами, а также в зависимости от внешнего кода создает различные реализации `ISomeInterface, ISomeInterface2` которые уже отправляются в класс-реализацию `IAddIn`

Comment: Строго типизированного механизма нет. Из нестрогих - Activator.CreateInstance. Но вообще то, что вы хотите - создавать экземпляры, которые зависят от других объектов - умеет любой ioc фреймворк.

Comment: Ага, есть. `Activator.CreateInstance`. И вообще-то можно взять готовые реализации DI/IOC, уточните: вам свой велосипед интересно пособирать или просто доехать надо?

Comment: В той точке, где вы решаете, какой конкретно класс у вас будет, в ней же вы и знаете, что передавать в конструктор.

Comment: Про `Activator.CreateInstance` знаю, можно также получить конструкторы на типе, но при динамической подгрузке может оказаться так, что различным классам требуются одинаковые параметры, например string (как для класса `B`), но ему параметр int не нужен и соотстветственно он требует только одного параметра. Единственное, что прослеживается - что все классы, реализующие `IAddIn` могут либо принимать реализации `ISomeinterface, IsomeInterface2`, либо их реализовывать. На крайний случай это может быть требованием

Comment: Используете DI контейнер и все дела. Есть хорошая книжка про это , автор по моему Mark Seeman, Dependency Injection in .NET